# Can not login to wordpress site after resolving white screen of death

Tags: login, errors, updates, debug, automatic-updates

I had a white screen of death that I was somewhat able to resolve.  I updated PHP from 7.0 to 7.3.2, removed BOM from wp-config.php, and deleted wp super cache plugin.  *From looking at others issues on this site, I deduced that it was caused by incomplete or broken automatic updates.*  I still see this on **/wp-login.php**

```
Warning: include_once(/hermes/bosnaweb21a/b783/apo.xyz/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ck/b783/apo.xyz/wp-content/advanced-cache.php on line 20

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/hermes/bosnaweb21a/b783/apo.xyz/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase1.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php-7.3.2-xenial/lib/php') in /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ck/b783/apo.xyz/wp-content/advanced-cache.php on line 20

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ck/b783/apo.xyz/wp-content/advanced-cache.php:20) in /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ck/b783/apo.xyz/wp-login.php on line 447

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ck/b783/apo.xyz/wp-content/advanced-cache.php:20) in /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ck/b783/apo.xyz/wp-login.php on line 462

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ck/b783/apo.xyz/wp-content/advanced-cache.php:20) in /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ck/b783/apo.xyz/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 928

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ck/b783/apo.xyz/wp-content/advanced-cache.php:20) in /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ck/b783/apo.xyz/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 929

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ck/b783/apo.xyz/wp-content/advanced-cache.php:20) in /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ck/b783/apo.xyz/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 930
```

**On home page** I see this at top of home page

```
Warning: include_once(/hermes/bosnaweb21a/b783/apo.northda5/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ck/b783/apo.xyz/wp-content/advanced-cache.php on line 20

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/hermes/bosnaweb21a/b783/apo.northda5/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase1.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php-7.3.2-xenial/lib/php') in /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ck/b783/apo.xyz/wp-content/advanced-cache.php on line 20
```

[image]

Any ideas how to fix?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you removed the WP Super Cache plugin: did you deactivate the plugin, or just delete the `plugins/wp-super-cache` directory? I suspect the latter, because it looks like your site is still trying to load WP Super Cache files.

You probably need to update your `wp-config.php` file to remove the `define( 'WP_CACHE', true );` line.

You might want to check this [support thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-wp-super-cache-2/), too, which discusses the steps you might need to take to completely remove WP Super Cache.

Comment: Thank you @Pat J! I first renamed that plug-in folder then deleted it. I will update wp config ASAP.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks again!